# Debug a C++ program with Textmate

Tags: debugging, textmate

I wonder whether it is possible to debug a C++ program with Textmate, using breakpoints, steps and so on, I googled a bit but found nothing relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use gdb. If you are not used to a text debugger it will be a bit of a shock at first, but I can tell you I can get around a lot faster in gdb than Eclipse, XCode, or VS.

Also, remote debugging is a cinch, and you can do it over a terminal or serial port if the display is busy.

I don't believe TextMate has integrated support for C++ debugging, either.